# How do I make sure a plugin loads a script after jQuery

Tags: plugins, jquery, wp-enqueue-script

My client has a site running the latest version of WordPress, with Thesis.

Currently, jQuery is being loaded in the footer, as the very last script to be loaded. I'm not sure what is causing jQuery to load - possibly Thesis, or something else.

We are adding a plugin, which has a script that loads. The script is being loaded in the footer. But it's being loaded BEFORE jQuery, so it fails.

The enqueue scripts line is this:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'stb_enqueue_scripts'));
```

I edited it to be this:

```
$deps = array("jquery");
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'stb_enqueue_scripts', $deps));
```

But that didn't solve the problem - in fact, the script no longer loaded at all.

How can I make sure this script loads after jQuery?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 8):

Using [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) or wp_print_script function you can load your JS file after jQuery loaded. Usage Reference -

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer ); ?>
```

The `$dep` argument **(dependencies)** should be an array or null or empty, and should not be used the way you did on your code. It will be on with [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) or wp_print_script function.

Your first used `add_action` reference is valid, but the second one is invalid.

On your `stb_enqueue_scripts` function, it should be -

```
function stb_enqueue_scripts()
{
    // third argument is the dependencies, should be array or boolean false
    // fifth argument = boolean true if loading the script at footer
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', 'script_url', array('jquery'), '', true );
}
```

Comment: That is the trick `array('jquery')` thanks